# Implicit slot names (auto-detect slot by a child tag name)

Tags: svelte

Suppose I'm writing my own component (`ModalWindow`) with a few slots, which are supposed to be occupied by specific sub-components (i.e. the `header` slot is supposed to contain `<ModalHeader>`):

```
<ModalWindow>
  <ModalHeader slot="header">Header stuff</ModalHeader>
  <ModalBody slot="body">Body stuff</ModalBody>
  <ModalFooter slot="footer">Footer stuff</ModalFooter>
</ModalWindow>
```

It would be neat to be able to omit the `slot="..."` bits and have the parent component sort the children into the appropriate slots automatically, based on the types of the child components:

```
<ModalWindow>
  <ModalHeader>Header stuff</ModalHeader>
  <ModalBody>Body stuff</ModalBody>
  <ModalFooter>Footer stuff</ModalFooter>
</ModalWindow>
```

*(An [article by Aha! Engineering](https://www.aha.io/engineering/articles/web-components-and-implicit-slot-names) goes into much more detail on this idea and describes a solution for WebComponents -- setting the `slot` in the child component's `constructor` -- which doesn't seem applicable to Svelte.)*

Svelte doesn't seem to support this natively, but **does it have any hooks that could be used to implement this? Any relevant discussions?**

---

As an aside, I could go the other way, specifying the slot name only via `svelte:fragment`:

```
<ModalWindow>
  <svelte:fragment slot="header">Header stuff</svelte:fragment>
  <svelte:fragment slot="body">Body stuff</svelte:fragment>
  <svelte:fragment slot="footer">Footer stuff</svelte:fragment>
</ModalWindow>
```

...and having the sub-components part of the parent component's definition (i.e. `<ModalHeader><slot name="header"/></ModalHeader>`), but that's uglier and doesn't allow using props on the child components.

Comment: as far as I know this is not possible but it would be nice to eventually be able to do this more elegantly, I opened an issue on the svelte github repository but for now you will be stuck specifying it

Comment: https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/8815

Comment: @StephaneVanraes thank you so much! Do you want to copy that in an answer, so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as far as I know this is not possible but it would be nice to eventually be able to do this more elegantly, I opened an issue on the svelte github repository but for now you will be stuck specifying it

https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/8815